# How to make a python code that's counts the cells more specifically and counts multiple types of cells?

Tags: python, cell, bioinformatics

I wanna preface this by saying 3 days ago I only knew how to code Print ("HEllO, World"). I'm very very new to this. I've used a few people codes and sandwiched them together.

My task is to create a code that can accurately count the cells in the picture and different types of cells too. In my workplace we have undreds of images we need to count.

I made a code that does count cells, But I had to adjust HSV everytime mannually and drag a new picture of cells everytime. THis is more time consuming than just counting cells by hand. How do I make this code count the cells accurately without counting as clusters, and without making it skip any cells?

So I made a configuration file with 2 types of cells, (will add more later once I experment with more cell types)

```
{
  "small cells large cluster": {
    "hsv_lower": [0, 0, 0],
    "hsv_upper": [179, 255, 150],
    "minimum_cell_area": 100,
    "maximum_cell_area": 100000,
    "average_cell_area": 450,
    "connected_cell_area": 10000
  },
  "Large cells small cluster": {
    "hsv_lower": [0, 0, 0],
    "hsv_upper": [179, 100, 175],
    "minimum_cell_area": 100,
    "maximum_cell_area": 2300,
    "average_cell_area": 750,
    "connected_cell_area": 1000
  }
}
```

these values that seemed to count the most 'correct' cells. However not all of them.
Below is code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import json
import os

# Load configuration from a JSON file
def load_config(config_file):
    with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)
    return config

# Load cell configuration
cell_config = load_config('cell_config.json.py')

# Prompt the user to choose a cell type
print("Available Cell Types:")
for cell_type in cell_config.keys():
    print(cell_type)

selected_cell_type = input("Enter the desired cell type: ")

# Check if the selected cell type is valid
if selected_cell_type not in cell_config:
    print(f"Error: Invalid cell type '{selected_cell_type}'.")
    exit()

# Access parameters for the selected cell type
config_params = cell_config[selected_cell_type]

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Cells images/cells two.webp').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
 
# Read the grayscale image using OpenCV
image = cv2.imread("greyscale.png")

# Check if the image is successfully loaded
if image is not None:
    original = image.copy()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
else:
    print("Error: Unable to load the image.")

# Access parameters from the configuration file
hsv_lower = np.array(config_params['hsv_lower'])
hsv_upper = np.array(config_params['hsv_upper'])
minimum_cell_area = config_params['minimum_cell_area']
maximum_cell_area = config_params['maximum_cell_area']
average_cell_area = config_params['average_cell_area']
connected_cell_area = config_params['connected_cell_area']

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)  # Adjust as needed
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# Display the 'mask' image
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # Waits indefinitely until a key is pressed
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Filter contours based on area
cells = 0

cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if minimum_cell_area < area < maximum_cell_area:
        cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
        if area > connected_cell_area:
            cells += math.ceil(area / average_cell_area)
        else:
            cells += 1

print('Cells: {}'.format(cells))
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Here are masking image and orginal image with count outlines. For reference the original image has 317 cells. And code only picks up 155 cells max. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj96F.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oq7A.png)